# How to make two or more html elements behave as a single unit in editable area

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider you have some contenteditable area with some content:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>first paragraph</p>
    <p>
        <img width='63' src='https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png'>
        <img width='63' src='https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png'>
    </p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

If you start navigate by left/right arrow keys caret start moving through all child elements. Please look this gif [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLpwq.gif)

The question is how to make caret ignore child elements? Or in any words: How to make behaviour of two images inside as a single image?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/izuick/UhfGc/)

Comment: Make one image out of it?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `<p>` containing the two images to a `<div>` with content editing turned off.

```
<div contenteditable="false">
    <img width='63' src='https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png'>
    <img width='63' src='https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png'>
</div>
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tfdMt/